# changing users default login shell on RHEL?

Tags: linux, rhel

Here is a command on free bsd

```
sudo pw usermod ksbuild -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

how do I do the equivalent on RHEL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chsh

(Change Shell)

Answer (score 7):

To change the default setting of all new users, edit the setting in the defaults file:
/etc/default/useradd

Answer (score 7):

Or for just a specific user:
usermod -s /usr/local/bin/bash ksbuild